# How do I fix my code to play a sound in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I've tried a lot of ways to get a sound to play in Java but none work. This is what I tried last:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound {

    public Clip load(String filename) {
        Clip clip = null;

        try {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(filename));
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return clip;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried clip.start()?

Comment: some ref - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

Comment: added the clip.start() but still getting a null pointer exception when i do: sound.load("path to file");